# What does the comma after a command do?

Tags: autohotkey

The [AutoHotkey Beginner Tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) starts off with an example using the `Send` command, with the command and its argument separated by a comma:

> ```
> ^j::
>    Send, My First Script
> Return
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `SEND` is the command, anything after the comma (,) will be typed.

Later, it gives an example of the `MsgBox` command with no comma:

> ```
> esc::
>     MsgBox Escape!!!!
> Return
> ```

Experimentally, it seems that including or omitting the comma makes no difference to the behaviour of a command, at least in these simple cases. We can change whether the comma is included in both examples above and the command still works: `MsgBox, Escape!!!` works, and so does `Send My First Script`.

Are there circumstances in which the syntax requires the comma (or forbids it)? Does the inclusion of the comma alter the semantics of the command in any way? Why are both syntaxes allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma (`,`) in AutoHotkey is a separator. The first (between the command and the first parameter) is [completely optional in most circumstances](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#esc):

> Tip: The first comma of any command may be omitted (except when the first parameter is blank or starts with := or =, or the command is alone at the top of a [continuation section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation)). For example:
>
> ```
> MsgBox This is ok.
> MsgBox, This is ok too (it has an explicit comma).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on this matter, quote from [commands and commas](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=39469):

> There are two ways of writing commands in AHK v1:
>
> ```
> ; initial commas
> Cmd, Arg1, Arg2
> Cmd, , Arg2
>
> ; no initial commas
> Cmd Arg1, Arg2
> Cmd , Arg2
> ```
>
> The no initial comma style can look a bit odd, confusing even, when you omit the first parameter.